# extracting or merging columns in a specific order in R

Tags: r, merge, extract

I have a longitudunal dataframe with more than 300 variables, a hospital database. For a certain clinical test I extract the test value and visit date for this test which corresponds also to test date as below with dplyr package:

```
df_VL<- select(df, ends_with("vload"))
df_dat<- select(df, ends_with("datvisit"))
```

then I `merge` these 2 with `cbind`:

```
df_x<- cbind(df_VL,df_dat)
```

but this gives me first all the test results then the test dates.

I need either 
to extract all the variables which ends `"vload"` and `"datvisit"` one by one in a chronological order like --> "t0datvisit", "t0vload","t6datvisit", "t6vload",......."t180datvisit", "t180vload"
or
to merge the columns of the two dataframe again according to this order --> "t0datvisit", "t0vload","t6datvisit", "t6vload",......."t180datvisit", "t180vload"

Any idea about how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `mapply` to map through both dataframe names and then cast to character vector for new column name order:

```
df_x <- cbind(df_VL, df_dat)

ord_names <- as.vector(mapply(c, names(df_VL), names(df_dat)))

df_x <- df_x[ord_names]
```

Comment: It works! thanks! to understand better the syntax: "c", what is it signifying? Sorry if it s stupid question,i m a beginner.

Comment: Great! If answered helped, please accept it (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution. The `c` refers to the [`c()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) base R function which combines values into vector or list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works

colnames( mtcars )[1:6]<- c(  "t0datvisit", "t0vload","t6datvisit", "t6vload","t180datvisit", "t180vload" )

```
# get all the numbers out of the colnames   
matches <- regmatches(colnames(mtcars), gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+",  colnames( mtcars)))
a<-unique( as.numeric(unlist(matches)) )
#order them numerically
a <- sort(a )

# create an object with the ars ordered numerically
f <- NULL 
for( b in a){ 
f <- c( f ,  paste0("t" , b, "datvisit") ,  paste0("t" , b, "vload")  )
}

# just those vars 
head( mtcars[ , f ] )

# or those vars and the other cols
others <- colnames( mtcars )[ !(colnames(mtcars) %in% f) ]
head( mtcars[ ,c( others, f)  ] )
```

if you want to do all the "datvisits" and than "vloads" its alot easier

```
head( mtcars[ , c( 
            grep(  "datvisit" , colnames( mtcars) ) ,
            grep(  "vload" , colnames( mtcars) )
            )])
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives an error: undefined columns selected, and I already have the df_x like your second suggestion but I want test result and its date side by side.

Comment: @trillian You need to replace mtcars with the name of your data set:  I just ran this line colnames( mtcars )[1:6]<- c(  "t0datvisit", "t0vload","t6datvisit", "t6vload","t180datvisit", "t180vload" )
 for testing